# HP DL360 G7 - shutdown / Power loss whilst idle

Tags: power

I had purchased a DL360 G7 for a home lab that i was looking to put together. I have a strange issue whereby the server appears to shutdown / lose power whilst its idle.

Specs 2 x 5650 CPU 24Gb RAM 3 x 146Gb 15k SAS disk - RAID 5 w/ p410i 256mb ESXI running from USB

I have installed version 6.5 of esxi onto the server and currently only have 2 vm's running on it.

So whilst i am actually using the VM's and resources are being consumed everything works perfectly no stability issues and do not notice any performance issues.

However, if i stop working on the VM's etc, essentially the system is sat idle waiting for some form of interaction. At random tines from what i can tell it loses power or shutsdown. I return to the server to find it is powered off but is in standby with power (Solid orange power button light) however the health light is flashing red with no lights on the pop out display at the front.

Now if i turn it on no messages are displayed about errors or failures. I have tried to pinpoint if it happens at specific times but i have known it to happen in as little as an hour of no use but then not happen until the next day. I have checked on the iLO module and it simply states the server lost power. However its not the electrics that have tripped as i have 2 other devices connected to the same outlet.

So far i have

Changed the power cable and reseated firmly
plugged it into its own power socket
flattened esxi and reinstalled (HP image, Vmware image, monster muffin image)
I am unsure if the esxi server is experiencing an issue and shutdowns to save itself (psod) but it does not cry that something unexpected had happened and the logs do not mean much to me but they do not appear to indicate some form of critical error.

I am at a bit of a loss now to figure out what is happening to it.

Does anybody know of any directories i can check on esxi that might show logs or contain core dumps etc.